# Sequence formed by quotient of sum and the product of odd squares is divergent: Why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Trust me when I tell you this is not homework. Can you suggest an solid argument to prove
$$ S_n = \frac{1}{3^25^27^2\cdots (2n-1)^2}\sum_{m=3}^{\infty} 2^{(2n)m}e^{-2^{m/2}} 
$$
diverges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

I have calculated $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ and $S_5$ 
$$ S_1 = \sum_{m=3}^{\infty} 2^{2m}e^{-2^{m/2}} =  13.63 $$
$$ S_2 = \frac{1}{3^2}\sum_{m=3}^{\infty} 2^{4m}e^{-2^{m/2}} =  1611.5$$
$$ S_3 = \frac{1}{3^25^2}\sum_{m=3}^{\infty} 2^{6m}e^{-2^{m/2}} =  511684$$
$$ S_4 = \frac{1}{3^25^27^2}\sum_{m=3}^{\infty} 2^{8m}e^{-2^{m/2}} =  3.42 \times 10^8 $$
$$ S_5 = \frac{1}{3^25^27^29^2}\sum_{m=3}^{\infty} 2^{10m}e^{-2^{m/2}} =  \frac{3.513 \times 10^{17}}{3^25^27^29^2} = 3.934 \times 10^{11} $$
and I am convinced it diverges, however, I'd like a more solid argument to rest my conjecture $S_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Thanks in advance. I will award 200pts bounty for a quality answer.

Comment: Can you give your results for $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4$, and $S_5$?  It would help confirm that we have the correct series in mind.  My intuition for the series I'm reading coincides with that of @InterstellarProbe, so perhaps I'm not getting the right series.

Comment: @BrianTung Sure. Just a second I'll edit the results in.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe do you have a link to that calculation? I can't get wolframalpha to hack it.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I figured out why it was giving that result. It was taking the limit first, then doing the summation. So, it was summing zero for every term.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook if you want to try the limit yourself, here is what I typed into wolframalpha (I'm not sure how to get links to display correctly in comments): Limit[Sum[2^(2m*(n+1))*e^(-2^(m/2)),{m,3,infinity}]/((2n+1)^2*Sum[2^(2m*n)*e^(-2^(m/2)),{m,3,infinity}]),n to infinity]

Comment: Keeping a single term in the series, chosen such that $2^{m/2}\approx n$, already suffices to show that $S_n\geqslant n^{2n+o(n)}$ hence $S_n\to\infty$.

Comment: Interesting, if Did is right ( and I hope so) then Wolframalpha fails to calculate this limit correctly. I was able to reproduce InsterstellarProbe's zero after cutting and pasting.

Comment: Yup, Did's right, it increases without bound.

Comment: Where did you encounter this series?

Comment: @BrianTung it's hard to explain at the moment, but as soon as I can I'll try to post a link.

Comment: @Did If Did or someone else interested would care to elaborate on why choosing a term such as $2^{m/2} \sim n$ suffices to show $S_n \geq n^{2n+o(n)}$ it would be very helpful. Also, I can't award Bounties to comments.

Comment: It may be interesting to note that $$\dfrac{1}{3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^2\cdots (2n-1)^2} = \dfrac{\pi}{4^n\left(\Gamma\left( n+\dfrac{1}{2} \right) \right)^2}$$ so the summation can be rewritten:  $$\dfrac{\displaystyle \pi \sum_{m=3}^\infty 4^{n(m-1)} e^{-2^{m/2}} }{ \left(\Gamma\left( n+\dfrac{1}{2} \right)\right)^2 }$$ which Wolframalpha still gets wrong: Pi*Limit[Sum[4^(n*(m-1))*e^(-2^(m/2)),{m,3,infinity}]/(Gamma[n+1/2])^2,n to infinity]

Comment: If @Did agrees with it, I can write something up. I can even put it as Community Wiki in that case (but then, better avoid a bounty... I don't think these are compatible).

Comment: @ClementC. go for it, no need for Community Wiki here. If Did wants credit I'm happy to award him another 200 after those I award you... provided the details are good. (Did has more than enough other answers for me to transfer points if it matters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This is detailing an observation made by [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862733/sequence-formed-by-quotient-of-sum-and-the-product-of-odd-squares-is-divergent/2862894#comment5906448_2862733).*

Note that, for $n\geq 3$,
$$
S_n = \frac{1}{(3\cdot 5 \cdot 7\cdots(2n-1))^2}\sum_{m=3}^\infty 2^{2nm} e^{-2^{m/2}}
= \left(\frac{2^n n!}{2n!}\right)^2\sum_{m=3}^\infty 2^{2nm} e^{-2^{m/2}}
$$ hence $$S_n\geq \left(\frac{2^n n!}{2n!}\right)^2 \max_{m\geq 3}2^{2nm} e^{-2^{m/2}}\tag{1}
$$
This (possibly quite loose) lower bound suggests to choose $m$ as close as possible to the maximizer of the function $f_n\colon[3,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f_n(x) = e^{2n x\ln 2-2^{x/2}}\,.
$$
Maximizing $f_n$ is equivalent to maximizing $\ln f_n$, which is done for $x$ such that $2^{x/2} = 4n$. Let 
$$2\log_2(4n)\leq m_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \lceil 2\log_2(4n)\rceil < 2\log_2(4n)+2$$
so that
$$
4n \leq 2^{m_n/2}< 8n\tag{2}
$$
Then,
$$
S_n \geq \left(\frac{2^n n!}{2n!}\right)^2 f_n(m_n) \geq \left(\frac{2^n n!}{2n!}\right)^2 2^{4n \log_2(4n)}e^{-8n} \stackrel{\rm def}{=} T_n\tag{3}
$$
Now, we rely on [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to bound the first factor of $T_n$:
$$
T_n \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{e^{2n}}{2^{2n}n^{2n}} \cdot 2^{4n \log_2(4n)}e^{-8n} = 2^{4n\log_2 n+O(n)} = n^{4n+o(n)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty \tag{4}
$$
By (3) and (4), we get finally
$$
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n = \infty}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Your $T_n$ is even more infinite than Did's original comment. Of course, a little infinity was all I needed, most appreciated. It's been a while since I tinkered with Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Well done (+1).